# Using Jenkins to Build OLP Schema Project

Tags: here-olp

I'm successfully using OLP Project Archetype to generate Schema project. Everything works fine locally, i can even deploy artifacts to OLP Artifactory. But this is because i have a settings.xml file generated by OLP to work with repo.

I need to have Jenkins jobd that will be building the project on every commit, and after merging to master brach (we are using Gerrit for code review that trigger pre-commit verify).  Do you have advices on how to configure it? I'm interested in how should i store my user/password there, and for which account it should be generated?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following steps apply to adding credentials in Jenkins.  There is more set-up in Jenkins.  This is only the credentials part.

Add Maven User Credentials

1. From the main Jenkins dashboard, select "Manage Jenkins".
2. Select "Credentials" from the left-hand side menu.  A "System" sub-menu should appear under "Credentials".
3. Select the "System" sub-menu.
4. Select "Global credentials".
5. Select "Add Credentials".

Import the Maven settings.xml file

1. From the main Jenkins dashboard, select "Manage Jenkins".
2. Search for and select the "Managed files" plugin.  This will take you to the "Config File Management" dashboard.
3. Select "Add a new Config".
4. Select "Maven settings.xml", and "Submit".
5. Select "Server Credentials Add".
6. "ServerId" is "HERE_PLATFORM_REPO".  (matching the  section from your settings.xml file)
7. Select the "Credentials" from above which are the username and password the settings.xml file downloaded from the Open Location Platform.
8. Copy the settings.xml file downloaded from the Open Location Platform, removing the username and password into the "Content" field.